# Custom Metadata Type: Editing SubscriberControlled field values in managed package

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata, field-mapping

I have a Custom Metadata Type which is part of a managed package I created. This type is used in order to map certain properties of a Salesforce Lead Object to some other custom properties of my own. For this to work I made sure the following things are set up correctly:

- the Custom Metadata Type's visibility is set to `Public`.
- the custom fields `fieldManageability` is set to `SubscriberControlled` for the fields that should be editable in the subscription org (e.g. `isActive__c`, `SalesforceLeadField__c` - see Screenshots)

When I try to change a field value in the Subscription Org there is a note on top of the field which says:

> This XXX Lead Mapping is managed, meaning that you may only edit certain attributes.
> Why? This XXX Lead Mapping is part of an upgradeable package installed from the AppExchange. What Can I Edit? For managed XXX Lead Mappings, the following items are editable: Protected Component, Salesforce Field, Active. To simplify the upgrade process, all other attributes are locked.

So all of the properties I want the subscribers to edit are actually listed in the help text. However, I can't even see them in the edit dialog. Only the the values which I cannot edit are visible (which is fine but where are the other ones?).

What am I missing here? It would be a pretty big problem for me if this won't work out this way as I would have to rethink the whole mapping logic.

Thanks in advance :).

[image: Example of custom field definition of my CMT]
[image: Example of the edit dialog in the subscription org]

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Did you add those fields (`Active`, `Salesforce Field`) to the page layout for that custom metadata?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Thank you and thanks for your quick answer. The fields were actually missing in my Page Layout. Though, I wonder why the other fields were visible by default since I didn't explicitly set them there either . I also missed to include a Page Layout for my CMT in my package so this should already fix my problem.